# Meteor - passing template variable as inner template argument

Tags: templates, meteor

I have a problem. I'm trying to pass a Template's variable in Spacebars HTML to a child template as an argument:

```
//Assume "var1" is a variable in a template:
<template name='example'>

    {{> childTemp val='hello{{var1}}'}}

    //Pass ^^ {{var1}} as an argument?

</template>
```

Normally, the above syntax works for passing the variable inside an HTML element, but it just shows up as the literal string 'hello{{var1})' in the output HTML

**Is it possible to pass a template variable as an argument in a child template/how?**

Comment: what is the intended purpose? You can use ```helpers``` / ```sessions``` to ```get``` and ```set``` the variable and then pass them to the child template when it is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `{{> childTemp val=var1}}` syntax, assuming you first do the following:

```
Template.example.onCreated(function () {
  this.var1 = "whatever";
});

Template.example.helpers({
  var1 () {
    return Template.instance().var1;
  }
});
```

Comment: I particularly mean inside a piece of text, like I displayed above. The {{var1}} variable is an ID, so I need something like 'hello{{var1}}' as an argument like you can do with standard HTML elements

Comment: As far as I know text interpolation is only done for DOM elements attributes, so you cannot really do the interpolation inline when you're passing parameters to your child components. They will be treated literally. You can still do the job inside a helper or implement a global helper that interpolates the given string based on keyword arguments provided.